# How to inject database connection to query handler?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, cqrs, simple-injector

I have an app which is similar to [this app](https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversityDotNetCore). Inside query handlers I use Dapper for getting data. DI container is SimpleInjector.

How should I inject a database connection in query handlers? Is it good to register IDbConnection in the DI container? What if I have several DB connections? How should I dispose them? Should a query handler be one for a http request (scoped) or be created with each request (transient)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create `DBConnectionFactory` which will create new instances of connections. Like this

```
public class DBConnectionFactory {
    public IDBConnection Create() { 
        // todo: read conn str from web.confing
        // create connection
    }
}
```

Register the Factory into the DI container and inject it in the Query Handlers.

**Sample scenario for Query handler**

- create connection from the factory
- execute query using the connection
- dispose connection

My advice is to use connections per query / command. Avoid using them per request, when it is time for updates, inserts, transactions you will see it can very messy.

For the `Command handlers` try to execute all the logic in single Command by wrapping all updates, inserts, deletes in a transaction.